# while making an alarm clock, a while loop continues to ask me to assign values even though they have been assigned

Tags: python

> so, i run the script and the while loop continues to ask me the times to assign even if they are not none anymore, my keyboard hasnt backsticks so don't ask me to use them, this is the code:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pygame
pygame.init()
now = datetime.now()
time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
hours = time[:2]
minutes = time[3:5]
seconds = time[6:]
if int(hours) <12:
    hoursdisplayed = f"{hours} AM"
else:
    hoursdisplayed = f"{int(hours)-12} PM"

alarm = pygame.mixer.Sound("C:\Users\bambini\Downloads\alarmclock.mp3")
while True:
    selectedhours = None 
    selectedminutes = None
    selectedseconds = None
    if selectedhours == None and selectedminutes == None and selectedseconds == None:
        selectedhours = int(input("Select the hour you want to wake up\n"))
        selectedminutes = int(input("Select the minute you want to wake up\n"))
        selectedseconds = int(input("Select the second you want to wake up\n"))
        if selectedhours >= 12:
            selectedhours -= 12

    elif hours == selectedhours and minutes == selectedminutes and seconds == selectedseconds:
        alarm.play()
```

ps: the "hoursdisplayed" variable will be used to display the time if a commands is used, or maybe i'll do it with a while loop too, the pygame module is used for the sound

i was expecting to wait until the selectedhours etc were equal to the hours but it just kept asking me to assign

Comment: You should assign these variables to `None` *outside* the loop. Otherwise they'll just be overwritten every time.

Comment: The first three lines of code at the top of the loop guarantee that those variable will **always** be equal to None....

Answer (score 1):

Just initialize the variables outside the `while True:` loop:

```py
import pygame
from datetime import datetime

pygame.init()

# Current time
now = datetime.now()
time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
hours = int(time[:2])
minutes = int(time[3:5])
seconds = int(time[6:])
if hours < 12:
    hoursdisplayed = f"{hours} AM"
else:
    hoursdisplayed = f"{hours-12} PM"

# Load alarm sound
alarm = pygame.mixer.Sound("C:\Users\bambini\Downloads\alarmclock.mp3")

# Initialize alarm time variables
selectedhours = int(input("Select the hour you want to wake up\n"))
selectedminutes = int(input("Select the minute you want to wake up\n"))
selectedseconds = int(input("Select the second you want to wake up\n"))
if selectedhours >= 12:
    selectedhours -= 12

# Alarm loop
while True:
    now = datetime.now()
    time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    hours = int(time[:2])
    minutes = int(time[3:5])
    seconds = int(time[6:])

    # Check if current time matches alarm time
    if hours == selectedhours and minutes == selectedminutes and seconds == selectedseconds:
        alarm.play()
        break  # Stop the loop if you want the alarm to play only once
```

Comment: Great. An improvement: `hours = now.hour` instead of parsing it from `strftime`.